# Google Charts API : Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Trying to use this code to create Google Charts from a csv file. This is the code I found being used on most tutorials. However there seems to some issues, due to which I cant execute it properly.

```
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {
   // grab the CSV
      $.get("Chart1-data.csv", function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0,1]);

     // set chart options
     var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
     };

     // create the chart object and draw it
     var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
```

I'm going by the tutorial. But on running it on the webserver it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined
```

If anybody knows the reason, please let me know whats happening and the solution to this error.

Comment: @ebyt You can find the API doc here https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: have you imported the library? `<script src="jquery-csv.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes. On importing I get `Uncaught Error: Unknown header type: null`

Comment: Are you building a NodeJS or Client-side app ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116836/discussion-between-ebyt-and-kandarp-gandhi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ebyt for pointing this out.

Placed

```
<script src="jquery-csv.js"></script>
```

after initializing jquery and works perfectly.

Comment: This is brilliant.  Mine was not exactly the same, but yes, re-arranging the order of the scripts is likely the solution.

Comment: @Max von Hippel Glad it could help you !